# Unable to connect to Lion server using finder, but able to using the lion server program?

Tags: vpn, osx-lion, osx-server

I have just set up a server at work. Its sits the other side of a substantial firewall and there for I VPN in to access it. The VPN appears to be functioning as I am able to access the server through the Lion server program and make server admin changes from at home. However I am unable to access the shared folders Which I am able to do easily at work n the network. Im a programmer and confess that I'm not the worlds best networker or server admin(everybody has to start somewhere). If anyone has had a similar problem please let me know. Much thanks

GC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case solved but don't ask me how. I tried accessing the shared files again and it worked. If you can explain that your a better man than me. Im going to put it down to a network issue.

Thanks for your time.